# align-items-* classes not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Based from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#alignment), when using the `align-items-*` classes, the `row` should changed its vertical alignment, but when I tried it, it didn't work:

```css
.con_1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container con_1">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <p class="col">
      Sample Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      Sample Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I add `height:100%;` to the `row`, it works, but encounters another problem, when adding multiple `row`, it aligns to the other `container`

```css
.con_1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.con_1 .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.con_2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container con_1">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <p class="col">
      Sample Text
    </p>
    <p class="col">
      Sample Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">Sample Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container con_2">
</div>
```

The documentation clearly shows that it only used one `container`, with multiple `row` and it worked properly. What did I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a basic rule of `flex` you cannot align items until it has a specifc `height`, either set `min-height` to `row` or make it a `flex-item` with `flex-grow:1` to adjust the heights.

```css
.con_1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.con_1 > .row{
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container con_1">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <p class="col">
      Sample Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      Sample Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where would I base the value of `min-height`?

Comment: I have updated my answer check it, and you will need to give `min-height` to `row` in case you don't want to use above answer.